# Create anonymous function in runtime JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have next code structure:

global.js and *.js for each page. Lets take for example global.js and main_menu.js.

I have some elements, that have class ripple_effect, when elements with this class get clicked, the animation begins that runs 650ms, so in order to let users see the animation i try to make a small delay in code ( i know this is not good, but still ).

in global.js i have next code:

```
var delayForRipple = 300;

function Execute(func) {
    setTimeout(func(), delayForRipple);
}
```

in main_menu.js i have next code:

```
$(this).on('click', ".menu_button", function (e) {
        href = $(this).attr('id');
        Execute(function () {
            window.location.href = href;
        });
    });
```

But this code executes immediately. How can i fix it?

Here is a fiddle for fast reproduction:

```js
var delayForRipple = 300;

$(".wrapper").on('click', "#clickMe", function (e) {
    Execute(function () {
        alert("TEST");
    });
});

function Execute(func) {
    setTimeout(func(), delayForRipple);
}
```

```css
.test_element {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="clickMe" class="test_element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` expects a function reference (or a string), but you're __calling__ `func()`, which doesn't return a reference, it just redirects ...

Comment: actually 300 ms is very short, you can't hardly see the delay. maybe you try with a higher number of ms

Comment: @mapodev tried more, set it to 10000 - still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing wrong ... you have to pass callback to setTimeout to be executed and not execute it yourselt there

Do something like

```
function Execute(func) {
   setTimeout(func, delayForRipple);
}
```

Or even remove the redundant Execute function

```
$(".wrapper").on('click', "#clickMe", function (e) {
   setTimeout(function () {
      alert("TEST");
   }, 650);
});
```

Comment: this is not redundant, i will use this functions on many other pages - that is why i dont want to duplicate the setTimeout

Comment: thanks, now i understood how this works. this will help me further. your answer is correct

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
function Execute(func) {
    setTimeout(func, 2000);   
}

Execute(function() {
   alert("test"); 
});
```

Comment: yes, thanks, Zohaib Ijaz was faster so i'm marking his answer as correct one, but will give you an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Change `func()` to `func` in `setTimeout`